# How to generate random color?

Tags: c#, arrays, colors

So I'm messing around in c#, and was wondering how to generate my string from an array, but with a random color:

```
    while (true)
        {
            string[] x = new string[] { "", "", "" };
            Random name = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine((x[name.Next(3)]));
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
```

When I'm outputting x, I want it to be a random color.
Thanks

Comment: Some more explanation would be good.  E.g. are you expecting `"Red"` or `"#FF0000"` or a `Color` of `Colors.Red` or ..?  Is there a set list of possible values or are you looking to generate random numbers for the R, G, and B components and then get the `Color` object for that (not necessarily with a nice English name)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the standard console colors, you could mix the [ConsoleColor Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolecolor.aspx) and [Enum.GetNames()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx) to get a random color.  You'd then use [Console.ForegroundColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.foregroundcolor.aspx) and/or [Console.BackgroundColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.backgroundcolor) to change the color of the console.

```
// Store these as static variables; they will never be changing
String[] colorNames = ConsoleColor.GetNames(typeof(ConsoleColor));
int numColors = colorNames.Length;

// ...

Random rand = new Random(); // No need to create a new one for each iteration.
string[] x = new string[] { "", "", "" };
while(true) // This should probably be based on some condition, rather than 'true'
{
    // Get random ConsoleColor string
    string colorName = colorNames[rand.Next(numColors)];
    // Get ConsoleColor from string name
    ConsoleColor color = (ConsoleColor) Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), colorName);

    // Assuming you want to set the Foreground here, not the Background
    Console.ForegroundColor = color;

    Console.WriteLine((x[rand.Next(x.Length)]));
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Comment: I noticed that the above code never set the console colors, it just retrieved a random color.  In addition, there were a few mismatched variable names.  I have fixed the code snippet.

Answer (score 7):

```
// Your array should be declared outside of the loop

string[] x = new string[] { "", "", "" }; 
Random random = new Random();     

// Also you should NEVER have an endless loop ;)
while (true)         
{            
     Console.ForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(random.Next(255), random.Next(255), random.Next(255));

     Console.WriteLine((x[random.Next(x.Length)]));             
     Thread.Sleep(100);         
}
```

Comment: What is Console.WriteLine((x[random.Next(3)])); doing in the code?

Comment: code typo: randonGen -> random

Comment: The user wants to output a random string contained in the x Array with a random color. Console.WriteLine will output one of the strings contained in the array because random.Next(3) will generate a number between 0 and 2, which will represent the position of the string wanted in the array. Therefore, is the random.Next(3) returns for instance 0, the first string in the array will be writin in the console.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have explained more.

Comment: I want to generate a color from an array(?), 

I want it to randomize eg. ConsoleColor.Red, or ConsoleColor.Green.

the code above isn't working for some reason, I get an error on Color

Comment: Color.FromArgb gives error can not implicitly convert type System.Drawing.Color to System.ConsoleColor